# Putting data onto different textures in WebGL and getting it out

Tags: glsl, webgl

I am trying to output more than one buffer from a shader - the general goal is to use it for GPGPU purposes. I've looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793336/webgl-2-0-multiple-output-textures-from-the-same-program) and got closer to the goal with this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    function main() {
        const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
        if (!gl) {
            return alert("need WebGL2");
        }
        gl.canvas.width  = 2;
        gl.canvas.height = 2;


        const vs = `
#version 300 es
in vec2 position;

void main(void) {
     gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
`;

        const fs = `
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

  layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor0;
  layout(location = 1) out vec4 outColor1;
  layout(location = 2) out vec4 outColor2;
  layout(location = 3) out vec4 outColor3;
  layout(location = 4) out vec4 outColor4;
  layout(location = 5) out vec4 outColor5;

  void main() {
    // simplified for question purposes
    outColor0 = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    outColor1 = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
    outColor2 = vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
    outColor3 = vec4(1, 1, 0, 1);
    outColor4 = vec4(1, 0, 1, 1);
    outColor5 = vec4(0, 1, 1, 1);
  } 
  `

        const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);

        const textures = [];

        const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

        for (let i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            const tex = gl.createTexture();
            textures.push(tex);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

            const width = 2;
            const height = 2;
            const level = 0;
            
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
            // attach texture to framebuffer
            gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, level);
        }

        gl.viewport(0, 0, 2, 2);

        // tell it we want to draw to all 4 attachments

        gl.drawBuffers([
            gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
            gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, 
            gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,
            gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3,
            gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT4,
            gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT5,                   
        ]);

        // draw a single point
        gl.useProgram(program);
        {
            const offset = 0;
            const count = 1
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE, 0, 4);
        }

        for (var l = 0; l < 6; l++) { 
            var pixels  = new Uint8Array(gl.canvas.width * gl.canvas.height * 4);
            
            gl.readBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + l);
            gl.readPixels(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

            console.log(pixels.join(' '));
        }
    }
    main();
})
```

However, the result is that only one pixel in each buffer gets set, so the output is:

```
0 0 0 0 255 0 0 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 255 0 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 255 255 0 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 255 0 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

rather than what I was hoping/expecting:

```
255 0 0 255 255 0 0 255 255 0 0 255 255 0 0 255
etc.
```

I was expecting that

```
outColor0 = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
```

is the equivalent to

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

but clearly I am wrong.

So how do I get to the desired outcome - to be able to set each pixel on each of the buffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not provide any vertex data even though it's asking it to draw 4 vertices. Further it's passing in `gl.TRIANGLE` which doesn't exist. It's `gl.TRIANGLES` with an `S` at the end. `gl.TRIANGLE` will be undefined which gets coerced into 0 which matches `gl.POINTS`

In the JavaScript console

```
> const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
< undefined
> gl.TRIANGLE 
< undefined
> gl.TRIANGLES
< 4
> gl.POINTS
< 0
```

To put it another way all the gl.CONSTANTS are just integer values. Instead of

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, offset, count)
```

you can just do this

```
gl.drawArrays(4, offset, count)
```

because `gl.TRIANGLES` = 4.

But you you didn't use `gl.TRIANGLES` you used `gl.TRIANGLE` (no `S`) so you effectively did this

```
gl.drawArrays(undefined, offset, count)
```

that was interpreted as

```
gl.drawArrays(0, offset, count)
```

0 = gl.POINTS so that's the same as

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, offset, count)
```

The code then draws a single 1 pixel point 4 times at the same location because you called it with a count of 4

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 4)
```

Nothing in your vertex shader changes each iteration so every iteration is going to do exactly the same thing. In this case it's going to draw a 1x1 pixel POINT at clip space position 0,0,0,1 which will end up being the bottom left pixel of the 2x2 pixels.

In any case you probably want to provide vertices but as a simple test if I add

```
  gl_PointSize = 2.0;
```

to the vertex shader and change the draw call to

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1); // draw 1 point
```

Then it produces the results you expect. It draws a single 2x2 pixel POINT at clip space position 0,0,0,1

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert("need WebGL2");
  }
  gl.canvas.width = 2;
  gl.canvas.height = 2;


  const vs = `
    #version 300 es
    in vec2 position;
    
    void main(void) {
         gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
         gl_PointSize = 2.0;
    }
    `;

  const fs = `
    #version 300 es
    precision mediump float;
    
      layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor0;
      layout(location = 1) out vec4 outColor1;
      layout(location = 2) out vec4 outColor2;
      layout(location = 3) out vec4 outColor3;
      layout(location = 4) out vec4 outColor4;
      layout(location = 5) out vec4 outColor5;
    
      void main() {
        // simplified for question purposes
        outColor0 = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
        outColor1 = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
        outColor2 = vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
        outColor3 = vec4(1, 1, 0, 1);
        outColor4 = vec4(1, 0, 1, 1);
        outColor5 = vec4(0, 1, 1, 1);
      } 
      `

  const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);

  const textures = [];

  const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

  for (let i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    const tex = gl.createTexture();
    textures.push(tex);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    const width = 2;
    const height = 2;
    const level = 0;

    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    // attach texture to framebuffer
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, level);
  }

  gl.viewport(0, 0, 2, 2);

  // tell it we want to draw to all 4 attachments

  gl.drawBuffers([
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT4,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT5,
  ]);

  // draw a single point
  gl.useProgram(program); {
    const offset = 0;
    const count = 1
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
  }

  for (var l = 0; l < 6; l++) {
    var pixels = new Uint8Array(gl.canvas.width * gl.canvas.height * 4);

    gl.readBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + l);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    console.log(pixels.join(' '));
  }
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

You can try using [webgl-lint](https://github.com/greggman/webgl-lint) which if I run with your original code will at least complain

> Uncaught Error: https://greggman.github.io/webgl-lint/webgl-lint.js:2942: error in drawArrays(/*UNKNOWN WebGL ENUM*/ undefined, 0, 4): argument 0 is undefined
> with WebGLProgram("*unnamed*") as current program
> with the default vertex array bound

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert("need WebGL2");
  }
  gl.canvas.width = 2;
  gl.canvas.height = 2;


  const vs = `
    #version 300 es
    in vec2 position;
    
    void main(void) {
         gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    `;

  const fs = `
    #version 300 es
    precision mediump float;
    
      layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor0;
      layout(location = 1) out vec4 outColor1;
      layout(location = 2) out vec4 outColor2;
      layout(location = 3) out vec4 outColor3;
      layout(location = 4) out vec4 outColor4;
      layout(location = 5) out vec4 outColor5;
    
      void main() {
        // simplified for question purposes
        outColor0 = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
        outColor1 = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
        outColor2 = vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
        outColor3 = vec4(1, 1, 0, 1);
        outColor4 = vec4(1, 0, 1, 1);
        outColor5 = vec4(0, 1, 1, 1);
      } 
      `

  const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);

  const textures = [];

  const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

  for (let i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    const tex = gl.createTexture();
    textures.push(tex);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    const width = 2;
    const height = 2;
    const level = 0;

    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    // attach texture to framebuffer
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, level);
  }

  gl.viewport(0, 0, 2, 2);

  // tell it we want to draw to all 4 attachments

  gl.drawBuffers([
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT4,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT5,
  ]);

  // draw a single point
  gl.useProgram(program); {
    const offset = 0;
    const count = 1
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE, 0, 4);
  }

  for (var l = 0; l < 6; l++) {
    var pixels = new Uint8Array(gl.canvas.width * gl.canvas.height * 4);

    gl.readBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + l);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    console.log(pixels.join(' '));
  }
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://greggman.github.io/webgl-lint/webgl-lint.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I might have clarifying questions at some point - but first I'll poke around until I've understood the answer fully

Comment: I wish there was a way to summarize these GPGPU-focused questions and answers somehow and give back to the community. Or are they too obvious except to me? or too niche? What do you think?

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer was not easy to understand. Updated the answer. I'm not sure what your level of understanding of WebGL is but maybe [this](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html) will help